# Vue JS. Pass prop via router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to have an array of dishes selected by user and their quantity in array `selectedDishes` in parent component and use this data in all other components in router. Here I have `dish` component, but I will use `selectedDishes` in `checkout` component etc.

1. How to pass `selectedDishes` to `dishes` component through router? Is it a correct to do so?(I read this [article](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) and it says only about getting `:dish` out of here `/dishes/:dish`)
2. I want to have access to `selectedDishes` only from parent component. So if I change quantity of dish in `dish` or `checkout` component it should be emitted to parent and then sent back as a prop to child components. Is it right to do so?

**Parent component**:

```
<template>
    <view-router v-on:addQuantity="addQuantity(...arguments)"></view-router>
</template>
<script>
    data: () => ({
        //How to pass this to dishes component?
        selectedDishes: [{name:'Soup', quantity: 10}, {name:'Sushi', quantity: 5}],
    }),
    methods: function(){
             addQuantity: function(dishName){
                        this.selectedDishes.forEach(function(item, index){
                            if(item.name == dishName){
                                this.selectedDishes[index].quantity +=1
                            }
                        })
             }
    }
</script>
```

**Router**:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require ('./components/vmMain'),
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dishes/:dish',
                component: require ('./components/Dishes')
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

**Dishes component:**

```
<template>
    <div
         // If URL is 'dishes/Soup' I want to see the following result
         //<h1>Soup</h1>
         //<h2>10</h2>
         <h1>dish.name</h1>//currently I access it as this.$route.params.dish
         <h2>dish.quantity</h2> //and don't have access to quantity
         <button v-on:click="addQuantity(dish.name)">add</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    methods: function(){
             addQuantity: function(dishName){
                        this.$emit('addQuantity', dishName)
             }
    },
    //How to pass prop from parent component?
    props['dish']
</script>
```

Comment: you should manage state in store instead of passing though router

Comment: @rupesh_padhye could you please provide more details or example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will create store for dishes something as below

```
 const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    dishes: [
      {

    name: '',
    quanity: ''
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getAllDishes: state => state.dishes,
    getDishByName: (state) => (name) => {
         return state.dishes.find(dish => dish.name === name)
    }
  },
  mutatations: {
  },

})
```

Dish name is available as path variable from vue router , you can query the store to get full details

For more understanding read below urls

[Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)

[Getting started vuex](https://scotch.io/tutorials/state-management-in-vue-getting-started-with-vue)